# c# how to get the install path of my program?

Tags: c#, windows-installer

guys.
In my program, i need to execute a kmlsample.exe in CMD, right now, it stays at my solution folder.
i can just do

```
string command = "\"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Bruce\\My Documents\\Visual Studio    2008\\Projects\\KMeans\\KMeans\\kmlsample.exe"
```

but when i let the user to install my program, how can i know the path of my program got installed,
in order to execute the exe file.

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be what your looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx

Edit - You need to run this *after* the install inside your main program right? This won't work if you need to run something *during* the install.

Comment: This only works for Windows Forms applications - not when you have a library project.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the executing assembly's location from

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```